# How to tell if there is one or more of an XML node

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I am creating a parsing script to pull data out of a file. I want it to gracefully handle scenarios where there is only one of a kind of child node or if there in more than one. Consider this XML.

```xml
<ClinicalDocument>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id></id>
      <addr></addr>
      <addr></addr>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

I could probably count on there only being one recordTarget, patientRole, and ID, but to make the parsing script bulletproof, I want to be able to easily test to see if there is more than one at each node level before I try to pull data from it. For example, if there is only one `<id>`, I would pull the data like this...

```
$xpath = $xml.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget
$id = $xpath.patientRole.id.extension
```

However, if there are two `<id>`s in the file, I need to pull the data like this...

```
$xpath = $xml.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget
$id = $xpath.patientRole.id[1].extension
```

I could access each node with a foreach, but it seems like waste if I only every want the first instance of each `<id>`. Is there a better way to deal with the single vs multiple items in a collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-Object`, specifying the first element should be selected, and the value of `extension` property assigned.

If there is only one, it'll just select that one.

```
$xpath = $xml.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget
$id = $xpath.patientRole.id | Select-object -First 1 -ExpandProperty extension
```

I used these xmls to test as your example didn't have an `extension` property:

**Single**

```
$xml = [xml] @"
<ClinicalDocument>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id extension = "A"></id>
      <addr></addr>
      <addr></addr>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
"@
```

**Multi**

```
$xml = [xml] @"
<ClinicalDocument>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id extension = "A"></id>
      <id extension = "B"></id>
      <id extension = "C"></id>
      <addr></addr>
      <addr></addr>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<extension>` tag is missing from your example. So I added it like this:

```
$xml = [xml]("<ClinicalDocument>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id>
        <extension>foo</extension>
      </id>
      <id>
        <extension>bar</extension>
      </id>
      <addr></addr>
      <addr></addr>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>")
```

If I get you right, you want always want the first `<id>` tag as a child of `<patientRole>`. In this case you can use XPath:

```
$recordTarget = $xml.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget
$id = $recordTarget.patientRole.SelectNodes('//id')[0].extension
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you can pull first value like this:

It is unclear whether the `.Extention` is a `node` or an `attribute` as the sample `xml` file doesn't include the extension.

In case the `.Extention` is an `attribute`:

```
$id = $xpath.patientRole.id.Extension | Select -First 1
```

In case the `.Extention` is a `node`:

```
$id = ($xpath.patientRole.id | Select -First 1).Extension
```